# Como puedo poner una imagen al lado de una lista, ya sea html o css?

Tags: html, css, lista

Supungo falta de experiencia, ya que creo que si se puede hacer, pero me la he pasado buscando como poner una imagen correctamente al lado de una lista y no he podido de ninguna forma.

Comment: Tienes codigo donde hayas intentado ponerlo, seria bueno para poder ayudarte

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado, un ejemplo verificable para poder ayudarte, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/547458/edit) tu pregunta y añade lo necesario las veces que quieras.

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow, por favor has el [tour] para entender cómo funcionamos y de paso ganar tu primer medalla. Te recomiendo que leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Debes colocar el código de lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento. Te sugiero que leas [example] para que sea más fácil entender lo que buscas. Recuerda que debes demostrar que has investigado previamente antes de recurrir a preguntar. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes utilizar un modelo como el siguiente:

```css
.list-and-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-and-image">
        <div>
        <img alt="Image" src="https://jessehouwing.net/content/images/size/w2000/2018/07/stackoverflow-1.png" width="200">
        </div>
        <div>
            <h5>Lista:</h5>
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).